# Why does 4**56 evaluate in Python as 5192296858534827628530496329220096L?

Tags: python, long-integer

Why does 4**56 evaluate in Python as 5192296858534827628530496329220096L? I'm wondering, why the `L`?

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I meant Python. erratum: Perl -> Python

Answer (score 1):

Because that number requires a long to store it, it won't fit in an int. Typically when displaying long values, consoles and such show the type suffix. You can find all the details about the number types [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex). Excerpt:

> Plain integers (also just called integers) are implemented using `long` in C, which gives them at least 32 bits of precision (`sys.maxint` is always set to the maximum plain integer value for the current platform, the minimum value is `-sys.maxint - 1`). Long integers have unlimited precision.

Comment: How do you display the actual result?

Comment: What are the limitations of numbers in Python?

Comment: @user3333975: *"How do you display the actual result?"* When I do a simple test (`print 4**56`), I don't get the `L` on the console.

Comment: How big of a number can it handle? What about 543 factorial?

Comment: It can handle arbitrarily large numbers -- the only limit is the RAM in your PC.